# Convolute of descrete and continous r.v.

Tags: probability, random-variables

$X\in Exp(a)\quad Y=[X]\Leftrightarrow Y\in Ge(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})\quad Z=X-[X]$

Show that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, and find the distribution of $Z$. $[X]$ is the integer function of $X$, and $a$ is a constant.  $\mathbf{J}$ is the jacobian.

$Z=X-Y$

$U=X-Y\quad V=Y\Leftrightarrow X=U+V\quad Y=V$

$\mathbf{J}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=1$

$1).$

$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X}(u+v)\cdot f_{Y}(v)\cdot |\mathbf{J}|$

$f_{U}(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(u+v)\cdot f_{Y}(v)\cdot 1 \, dv=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u+v)}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(v)}\, dv$

$=\frac{1}{a}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-1}{a}(2v)}\, dv=\frac{1}{a}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\Big[\frac{-a}{2}e^{\frac{-2}{a}(v)}\Big]_{0}^{\infty}$

$=\frac{1}{a}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}}\Big(0-(\frac{-a}{2})\Big)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}$

$f_{Z}(z)=f_{U}(u)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}$

$2).$

$f_{U}(u)=\sum_{v=0}^{\infty}f_{X}(u+v)\cdot f_{Y}(v)\cdot|\mathbf{J}|=\frac{1}{a}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\sum_{v=0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-1}{a}(2v)}$

$=\frac{1}{a}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\Big(\frac{e^{\frac{2}{a}}}{e^{\frac{2}{a}}-1}\Big)=\frac{1}{a}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{a}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{a}}}\cdot e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{a}}e^{\frac{1}{a}}}{(e^{\frac{1}{a}}-1)(e^{\frac{1}{a}}+1)}$

$=\frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{a}}}{(e^{\frac{1}{a}}+1)}$

$f_{Z}(z)=f_{U}(u)=\frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{-1}{a}(u)}\cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{a}}}{(e^{\frac{1}{a}}+1)}$

Is any of these correct?